# No logro obtener las características de los componentes de la pc en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

le comento el programa se ejecuta sin ningún problema solo que no arroja las características de los componentes del ordenador :

aquí le dejo el código:

```
private void MuestraInformacion1(String Key)
    {

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        ListViewGroup lstvg;

        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
            {

                try
                {
                    lstvg = listView1.Groups.Add(objeto["Name"].ToString(), objeto["Name"].ToString());
                }
                catch
                {

                    lstvg = listView1.Groups.Add(objeto["Name"].ToString(), objeto["Name"].ToString());

                }

                if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }

                foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
                {
                    ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(lstvg);

                    listViewItem1.Text = PropiedadObjeto.Name;

                    if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
                        listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //informacion nula
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pueden obtener datos \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }



// Por medio de un evento mano a llamar el método:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MuestraInformacion1("Win32_Processor");
    }
```

[image: En la imagen le dejo como corre el programa notaran que solo me arroja el nombre de los valores pero no su valor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia tú método `MuestraInformación1` por el siguiente:

Le hice algunos cambios, pero la falla básicamente era que el tipo de vista para el `ListView` debería ser `View.Details`, además hay que adicionar dos columnas para diferenciar la información mostrada y al final de las asignaciones faltaba adicionarle el `ListViewItem` al `ListViewGroup`:

```
private void MuestraInformacion1(String Key)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    // ************************************
    // Propiedades adicionadas al ListView
    // ************************************ 
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Propiedad");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Valor");

    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);
        foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
        {
            // ************************************
            // Se obtiene el key para el grupo adicionado
            // ************************************
            string grupo = objeto["Name"].ToString();
            listView1.Groups.Add(grupo, grupo);

            if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }


            foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
            {
                ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(PropiedadObjeto.Name);                        
                if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
                }
                listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);

                // ************************************
                // Se adiciona el ListViewItem al Grupo creado anteriormente
                // ************************************
                listView1.Groups[grupo].Items.Add(listViewItem1);
            }                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pueden obtener datos \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @JohnnyGR, si te servio la respuesta no olvides marcarla como correcta.